# How to show open tabs on other devices on Mac Safari?

Tags: icloud, safari, tabs

I want to show open tabs on other devices that share the same Apple and iCloud account, but for some reasons there is no open tab on Mac Safari when I click the top-right icon (the icon of two tabs overriding).

On my iPhone and iPad I can access the tabs opened on my Mac, but the other direction is not true. How can I open the tabs opened on iOS devices on Mac or maybe is it just a bug?

---

#### UPDATE

I found out that sometimes the tabs appear properly whereas other times they don't.

#### UPDATE 2

This might be a bug, but I think 60~80% of the time the tabs don't appear. I upgraded to macOS 11.1 but the problem still persists. Any workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: What Safari and OS version are you on? There seems to be a bug in Safari 14 on macOS.

Comment: @Gummibando Both are the latest version. It’s on 2020 MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a bug. Im guessing the bug is in iCloud.
Apple's documentation says it should work the way you were doing it:
https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT202530

Comment: Without changing anything on my Mac or iDevices the functionality has been restored for me. You too?